# Intellij can't load ModelBuilderService$Ex class

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I was working normally with the IDE when this message appeared:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI6IC.png)

At first the problem appears only in one project but then many other projects started failing.
How can i fix it?
I'm using gradle 4.10 (this is the standard in my work so i can't update the version) and the intellij is the 2020.3.

Comment: Did you lately upgrade the IntelliJ version? If yes try to completely reinstall IntelliJ and Gradle. When I updated to version some of the plugins I had completely stopped working. But I fixed it with reinstalling the software.

Comment: Have you updated Kotlin plugin? Looks like [KTIJ-866](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-866). Please make sure to use the latest IDE version https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and the latest Kotlin plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I fixed it by going to `File > Close Project` then to `Help > Check for Updates` and installing the updates, had to `Check for Updates` twice to get them all, your mileage may vary.